# Type mismatch error for filter function with dplyr over a spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I am currently working on Rstudio over a rhel cluster.
I use spark 2.0.2 over a yarn client & have installed the following versions of sparklyr & dplyr

sparklyr_0.5.4 ;
dplyr_0.5.0

A simple test on the following lines results in error

```
data = copy_to(sc, iris)
filter(data , Sepal_Length >5)

Error in filter(data, Sepal_Length > 5) : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I checked with the read & all looks fine

```
head(data)
Source:   query [6 x 5]
Database: spark connection master=yarn-client app=sparklyr local=FALSE

Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
     <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>   <chr>
1    5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
2    4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
3    4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
4    4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
5    5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
6    5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    setosa
```

is this a known bug & are there known fixes for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. You have to specify that you want to use the `filter` function from the `dplyr` package. Probably you are using the `filter` function from the `stats` package. That's why you get that error. You can specify the right version with this: `dplyr::filter`

```
res <- dplyr::filter(data, Sepal_Length > 5) %>% dplyr::collect()
head(res)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>   <chr>
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
3          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
4          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
5          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
```

To be sure, in the RStudio console, just type `filter` (or any other function) and check the popup with the function name that appears. On the right, you can see the package that it's going to be used if you don't explicitly name the package with `::`.